# Text citation-superscript numerals

Tags: citing

I use `\usepackage[superscript]{cite}` in my LaTeX. But it gives "...analysis. `$^{?}$`". I want text citation like "...analysis. `$^{1}$`".  How should I do for this?

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}

\usepackage[superscript]{cite}

\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2015}

\begin{document}

The performance … \cite{Venables et al.}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Venables et al.(2016)]{Venables et al.}
Venables~WN, Smith~DM and the R Core Team. Notes on R: a programming environment for data analysis and graphics.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) we need to know more about your document. A simple guess: you either have not compiled enough times, have misspelled the citation key or have forgotten to run bibtex.

Comment: Update your question with this information. Citation keys should not contain spaces. You are not using bibtex I can see. Did you compile enough times? I'm not at a pc so cannot test

Comment: I added more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip if you highlight the code in the editor and hit ctrl-k every thing gets indented and the code is nicely formatted. That bibtex command is irrelevant for the example.

Comment: Also for those trying to help, where does one get the `sagej ` class. Btw does the citation work without the superscript option? Does the example work if you use the article class instead.

Comment: No, it does not work if I use article class.

Comment: I have to use sage class from the journal too.

Comment: With two LaTeX runs I get the `?` replaced by the key, but I suspect the class is not expecting an author-year style set up. I also note the class comes with a `.bst`: is there a reason you are not using BibTeX?

Comment: I got "?" too. I have to use the class from journal's template. however, if you have any idea to me. I will try to work. Thanks @JosephWright

Comment: @user121684 Sure, you have to use the class but you don't have to do the bibliography by hand. There's an [example of using `sagej` on Overleaf](sagej.cls): looks fine but they don't seem to use superscript citations.

Comment: So I need to do in sagej.cls? I don't know how to fix it. Sorry I am a new user. This is info.   https://studysites.uk.sagepub.com/repository/binaries/pdf/SAGE_Vancouver_reference_style.pdf

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the `sagej` class [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sage-latex-guidelines-a-demonstration-of-the-latex2e-class-file-for-sage-publications/mtbgkxvdfrjw) (download link in Abstract).

Second, I would recommend using `natbib` package with option `super`. Here is what the minimal code looks like

```
\documentclass{sagej}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\begin{document}

This is the cited text \cite{jd12}, here is another one \citet{jd13}
and here \citep{jd14}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{mybib}{}

\end{document}
```

The `mybib.bib` contains

```
@article{jd12,
 author={Doe, J. and Bar, F. and Smith, J.},
 title={Some title 1},
 journal={Some journal},
 year={2012},
}

@article{jd13,
 author={Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
 title={Some title 2},
 journal={Some journal},
 year={2013},
}

@article{jd14,
 author={Doe, J. and Simpson, H. and Bar, F.},
 title={Some title 3},
 journal={Some journal},
 year={2014},
}
```

After compiling I get the following pdf, where you may notice what different citation commands (used above) do. I guess you wanted the result produced by `\cite{}`.
[image]